# How to Transfer a file from ACC to Forge's OSS using?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I'm looking for guidance on transferring a file from Autodesk Construction Cloud to Forge's Object Storage Service using C#. I found a sort of approache([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153783/uploading-a-file-from-autodesk-a360-to-bucket-in-nodejs)) but doesn't seem very clear. Specifically, I'm interested in:

1. Getting a file in ACC.
2. Uploading a file directly to Forge's OSS without downloading it locally.

Any examples or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: it seems you have a discussion with my Autodesk colleague, and he told us that you actually want to send the file from Autodesk Docs to DA, I will answer the question based on this situation

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to move files from Autodesk Docs to Autodesk OSS, basically, you have to download it and upload it through the normal way. Check details as:

1. Download file from Autodesk Docs:
   https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/
2. Upload file to Autodesk OSS:
   https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/

But for many user senario, for example, if you want to send the file from Autodesk Docs as input to Design Automation, you can send them directly, check details at https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-feature-support-direct-s3-migration-inputoutput-files-design-automation .